# Oracle Forms Fatal Error FRM-92102: A network error has occurred

Tags: oracle, fatal-error, oracleforms

FRM-92102: A network error has occurred.

Where this error message is Written. I want to override this message once and can be used for all Forms. I do not want to write error-handling code for this method on each Oracle form

Answer (score 0):

you can use `on-error` trigger and override the message in it

Comment: I tried handling error using on-error trigger but it did not work.